# UWP appx install web error - cannot open appx

Tags: iis, uwp, appx

I am trying to setup a page to install an appx UWP app as per this blog:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appinstaller/2017/09/26/uwp-app-installs-from-web-via-app-installer/

I have generated my app package files, created a new site on IIS with a basic index.html with a link

```
<a href="ms-appinstaller:?source=http://localhost:89/MySampleApp_0.0.1.0_x86.appx">Install appx package</a><br>
```

When I run the appx file through explorer it installs fine. When I open it from the link above it launches the app installer but with the error:

**Cannot open appx/appxbundle/appinstaller file. Reason: Error in parsing the appx/appxbundle/appinstaller**

I don't know much about IIS but I assume this is something to do with accessing the install files.
If I remove the

```
ms-appinstaller:?source=
```

part the file downloads ok because  I setup a mimetype.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I am using a self signed cert. Is this the problem?

Comment: Can you access the source url and get the .appx file in the web browser?

Comment: Yes I can. I remove ms-appinstaller:?source= from the link I can download the appx file through the browser. I should also point out I am using a self signed cert if that makes any difference?

Comment: Could you provide your device OS version and your app target and min version?

Comment: Device is 16299.371. Target version is 16299. Min version is 16299. I am going to try testing with this with a brand new blank UWP app created in VS 2017

Comment: Tried this (new blank app) - made no difference. Could it be a file permissions issue with permissions to some of the files/folders like the Dependencies folder? I tried changing the link to file:////c:/TestSite/TestWebInstallApp_1.0.0.0_x86_Debug.appx and this crashes the app installer

Comment: I have tried this on another machine - same issue. So it is not the app installer, not the appx bundle. It has to be how the files are being hosted on IIS. Can anyone advise? I have limited knowledge of IIS

Comment: As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/web-install-iis#step-8---add-loopback-exemption-for-app-installer) about this topic, due to network isolation, UWP apps like App Installer are restricted to use IP loopback addresses like http://localhost/. When using local IIS Server, App Installer must be added to the loopback exempt list. Please see the document to get the details.

Comment: YES!! I have been waiting a long time for this thanks. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by Breeze Liu in the comments. Setting a loopback exemption as described here resolves the issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/web-install-iis#step-8---add-loopback-exemption-for-app-installer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article about it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/web-install-azure

In summary, 3 things to check.

First, make sure the app package files are uploaded to the location that's specified (Installer location highlighted below).
[image]

Second, install the certificate that the app package is signed with if you are using your own certificate.

Last, make sure you configure the web app for app package MIME types. In web.config file, add the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--This is to allow the web server to serve resources with the appropriate file extension-->
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".appx" mimeType="application/appx" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".msix" mimeType="application/msix" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".appxbundle" mimeType="application/appxbundle" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".msixbundle" mimeType="application/msixbundle" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".appinstaller" mimeType="application/appinstaller" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```